# Spring batch config with multiple state recording writes in one step

Tags: spring-batch

I am implementing the following config in Spring Batch and I am wondering what the best approach would be:

```
ItemReader ---> item ---> processor ---> processor -> processor -> ... processor -> itemWriter

                            |              |              |
                    Write state to DB    Write...       Write...
```

so the item is read from the database and each item goes through multiple units of processing which are serial(**not parallel**) before the final writer finishes it up by writing the result.
It looks like this could be done via listeners... what would be the best approach here? Thanks.

P.S.
What I had in mind was something like this, which does not seem possible using only one step:

```
ItemReader->item -> process -> write -> process -> write -> ...process ->itemWriter
```

Comment: I would not make db writes in an item processor. Should all these writes be done in a single transaction? From the title I see you are trying to do everything in one step, and it seems like the chunk-oriented processing model is not suitable for your use case. Is using multiple sequential steps an option for you?

Comment: The thing is I run a MongoDB aggregate query in the first itemReader,which cannot be done( as far as I know) with MongoItemReader as it only uses the find method, and the result is a list of items. so I pull in the list in the first read, and then process one by one. Multiple sequential steps sounds like the right approach, I just dont know how to implement the first read to make it work like this...

Comment: What would you suggest for a forEach type situation with data flowing from top to bottom like this: ReadAll(to be reduced to a single item read from mongo if possible) -> forEach(1. readItem 2. process 3. write 4.process 5. write 6.process... writeItem). the key here is that the a piece of data is shared by all the sequential steps with changes to it.

Comment: You can try to implement something similar to [SEDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staged_event-driven_architecture) style by using blocking queues as medium to carry items between steps. I implemented a PoC with two steps here: https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-lab/blob/master/issues/batch1538/src/main/java/com/example/demo1/ConcurrentStepsSample.java. You can adapt it to add more stages to the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Modified the diagram below.

```
ItemReader->item -> CompositeItemProcessor->itemWriter

CompositeItemProcessor is a serial processor you  can add multiple processors 

  public ItemProcessor<Document,Document> compositeItemProcessor() {
    CompositeItemProcessor processor = new CompositeItemProcessor<>();
    ArrayList<ItemProcessor<Document,Document>> delegates = new ArrayList<>();
    delegates.add(tikaItemProcessor);
    delegates.add(pdfBoxItemProcessor);
    delegates.add(metadataItemProcessor);
    delegates.add(webserviceDocumentItemProcessor);
    processor.setDelegates(delegates);
    return processor;
}
```

Please find the API documentation below

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemProcessor.html